# How do I deploy an Azure WebJob alongside a .NET Core Web App via Git?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, azure, azure-webjobs, kudu

I thought this would be a pretty straightforward task and there is quite a bit of documentation out there but I've had zero luck with any of it and am assuming that it is pretty much all out of date.

I have .NET Core MVC 6 Web App that I've been developing for a while and need to set up a WebJob for it on Azure. I want to deploy this alongside the app using the continuous deployment system Azure provides that the app is already using. According to Kudu docs it's possible:

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-Jobs#deploying-net-console-webjobs-alongside-an-aspnet-application

Which states:

> This works both when deploying directly from Visual Studio
>   (WebDeploy), or via git.

It references this link (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/), which I've been attempting to follow with no success.

I have the latest version of Visual Studio 2015, .NET Core 1.0.0 & Tools and the Azure SDK.

First thing that becomes apparent is that I do not have the scaffolding options as shown in the screenshots on the Azure docs and after failing to find any missing dependencies I resorted to trying to set it up manually as described.

Even after putting the required files in the locations specified (`webjobs-list.json` and `webjob-publish-settings.json`) and configuring them for my project, and adding `Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish` to the WebJob project, Kudu does not find the WebJob via the continuous deployment system.

I've tried several approaches and variations based on the documentation I've found out there but I just can't get it working and all other SO questions are year(s) old.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Is this even still possible with the latest version of .NET Core MVC?

Comment: I don't think VS has the support yet to deploy WebJobs with Core apps.

Comment: @DavidEbbo Then the docs should reflect this instead of the contributors just touching the date on the docs to make it appear like they are recent and up to date. Completely misleading!

Comment: @DavidEbbo Any updates on this? Right now .Net Core Console App WebJobs need to be deployed throgh the Portal and cannot be deployed alongside an Asp.Net Core project as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958252/azure-webjob-removed-after-app-service-publish-with-autoswap

Comment: From what I hear from the VS tooling team, that work is upcoming. Sorry, I don't have an ETA to share.

Comment: @MathiasR I actually have a working solution for this now that is reliable. Currently swamped with work but I'll see if I can make some time to post up the answer next week (still need to generalise the solution as it's specific for my project).

Comment: *Bump* @DavidEbbo One year later, is this possible - are there docs for doing this with .net core 2?

Comment: They recently added the option to publish standalone Core WebJobs, but not WebJobs alongside Web App.

Comment: @DavidEbbo, is there any plan to have the dual deployment? Or should we simply use a similar solution as in the below answer?

Comment: @JulienJacobs sorry, I do not know. Maybe worth reaching out on [VS forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/home?category=visualstudio)

Answer (score 10):

WebJobs' files are stored under the 'App_Data/jobs/continuous' or 'App_Data/jobs/triggered' folders, so one way I could use to deploy both Web App and WebJob is manually copying all WebJobs' files needed to these folders during build time. I think this will fit while VS tooling is being updated.

My solution is a little different from yours since I'm using Visual Studio Team Services to build and release my app to Azure, but the concept is the same. You can use a post build event in Visual Studio to run a script that copies these files to the jobs' folder.

Below are the steps I've configured in VSTS build definition:

1. Command Line task:
   **Tool:** dotnet
   **Arguments:** restore
2. Visual Studio Build task:
   **Solution:** **\MyApp.sln
   **Platform:** $(BuildPlatform)
   **Configuration:** $(BuildConfiguration)
   **Visual Studio Version:** Visual Studio 2015
3. Command Line task:
   **Tool:** dotnet
   **Arguments:** publish -c $(BuildConfiguration)
4. Command Line task:
   **Tool:** dotnet
   **Arguments:** publish -c $(BuildConfiguration) $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\src\MyApp.Jobs\project.json
5. Copy Files task (this is the trick):
   **Source folder:** src/MyApp.Jobs/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/netcoreapp1.0/publish/
   **Contents:** **
   **Target folder:** src/MyApp.Web/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/netcoreapp1.0/publish/App_Data/jobs/triggered/MyJobName/
6. Archive Files task:
   **Root folder (or file) to archive:** src/MyApp.Web/bin/$(BuildConfiguration)/netcoreapp1.0/publish/
   **Prefix root folder name to archive path:** unchecked
   **Archive type:** zip
   **Archive file to create:** website.zip
   **Replace existing archive:** checked
7. Copy Files task:
   Source folder:
   **Contents:** **/*.zip
   **Target folder:** $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
8. Publish Build Artifacts task:
   **Path do publish:** $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
   **Artifact Name:** drop
   **Artifact type:** Server

Comment: Awesome! After hours of banging my head you saved my project =]

Comment: If you don't see the web job in kudu. add run.cmd and set to copy always :)