# Azure WebJob removed after App Service publish with Autoswap

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

We have an Asp.Net Core Azure App Service. We have added one deployment slot, to which we deploy. This slow has Autoswap enabled.

When we deploy a new version .Net Core Console app WebJob we have added in production, it is removed.

The question is, when will it be possible to publish a WebJob alongside an Asp.Net Core project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated ins [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064071/how-to-prevent-azure-webjobs-from-being-swapped-in-azure-website-production), a Web job is part of the App service content.

So when switching from one slot to another, you are switching **the whole App Service content**, which includes switching **Webjobs**.

Comment: But the WebJob is not in the "Staging" slot either. I have uploaded the WebJob manually through the portal and it is not deployed from Visual Studio.

Comment: You have your answer: I am pretty sure that uploading you webjob manually is causing your issue. Give a try & deploy it using Visual Studio tooling