# How to publish .net core WebJob together with asp.net core web app?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-webjobs

I have a two net core console apps that I deploy to Azure as web jobs using visual studio.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk;Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish">
```

It works well, when I publish them separately.

### How do I publish .net core webjobs togeter with web app?

I have tried create `webproject/properties/webjob-list.json`. Paths are relative to webproject/webproject.csproj:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjobs-list.json",
  "WebJobs": [
    {
      "filePath": "../PeopleWebJob/PeopleWebJob.csproj"
    },
    {
      "filePath": "../Reminder/ReminderWebJob.csproj"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've also tried to install `Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish` nuget, but it looks like this approach is not working for .NET Core.

Alternativelly,

### How do I publish the webjobs using VSTS?

I've tried to `dotnet publish` the WebJob project and copy the output to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/webproject.zip/App_Data/jobs/Triggered`

Answer (score 4):

It is **not** supported for **VS** to deploy WebJobs along with **.NET Core Apps** yet.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919723/how-do-i-deploy-an-azure-webjob-alongside-a-net-core-web-app-via-git) is a similar issue, you could refer to it. To publish the webjobs via VSTS, you could refer to this [link](https://daniel.blomskog.blog/deploy-net-core-webjob-azure/).

Besides, you can also zip it up and use the **Azure Portal** to create the WebJob  or use [**Kudu Console**](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) or FTP to do it.

Comment: The link you have send regarding VSTS is for classic .NET Framework.

Comment: @Liero Sorry for my oversight, I have changed the link, you could refer to it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you copy the necessary output to `webproject.zip/App_Data/jobs/Triggered` (do not zip published web project during dotnet publish, then copy files and zip files through Archive Files task), you just need to publish the project through **Azure App Service Deploy** task.

Package or folder: `{the website zip file}`

Check **Publish using Web Deploy option** in Additional Deployment Options section

Comment: You said: "Since you copy the necessary output to webproject.zip/App_Data/jobs/Triggered". Is there any other option? This copying is a little bit unpractical, because I have to configure with project goes to Triggered and which to Continuous folder in App_Data/jobs and it means editing build definition each time there is new or renamed WebJob,

Comment: @Liero You can do it programmatically (e.g. PowerShell), then run the script during VSTS build. Can't find the way to publish the .net core web jobs directly.